# How to remove the background in NavigationLinks?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigationview

How do I remove the background color of navigation link(The gray stuff).
[image]
I have tried setting the background color to clear, but that does not seem to do anything:

```
struct DesignView: View {

@State var index: Int
@State var selection: Int


var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .center){
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 90.0)
            .fill(Color.white)
            .frame(height: 50)
        
        NavigationLink(
                destination: GraphView(type: selection, index: index),
                label: {
                    Text("Warm Up #\(index)")
                        .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .backgroundStyle(
                            Color.clear
                        )
                })
        .backgroundStyle(
            Color.clear
        )
   
        .padding()
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It didn’t work for me by setting `.backgroundStyle(Color.clear)` or `.tint(Color.clear)`.

You can achieve this using `.buttonStyle(.plain)` on the NavigationLink.

```
NavigationLink(
    destination: GraphView(type: selection, index: index),
    label: {
        Text("Warm Up #\(index)")
            .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                .foregroundColor(.black)
    })
.buttonStyle(.plain)
```

There's one more way to achieve this - you can find it [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-disable-the-overlay-color-for-images-inside-button-and-navigationlink).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

Navigation Links respond to tint, not to the bcgrnd color for that purpose:

```
NavigationLink(
                destination: GraphView(type: selection, index: index),
                label: {
                    Text("Warm Up #\(index)")
                        .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .backgroundStyle(
                            Color.clear
                        )
                })
        .tint(Color.clear)
        .backgroundStyle(
            Color.clear
            
        )
```